# How can I reload a jquery tab on form submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I use jquery for ajax tabs, not jquery UI that is to large for my needs
This code below is my ajax tabs, it loads the selected tab with an external file

I also have a for that uses ajax to post data to this page HOMEfriendstatus.inc.php which is #tab2

What I want to know when I submit the form, regardless of what tab the user has loaded on the screen, can I make it reload or change to #tab2 to show the updated content of #tab2?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageUrl = new Array();          
pageUrl[1] = "HOMEbulletin.inc.php";
pageUrl[2] = "HOMEfriendstatus.inc.php";
pageUrl[3] = "HOMEbulletin.inc.php";



function loadTab(id){
    if (pageUrl[id].length > 0){
        $("#loading").show();
        $.ajax({url: pageUrl[id], cache: false, success: function(message) {                            
            $("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
            $("#loading").hide();             
        }
    });                 
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    /*$("#tab1").addClass('selected');*/
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#tab1").click(function(){
        loadTab(1);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#tab2").click(function(){
        loadTab(2);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#tab3").click(function(){
        loadTab(3);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You do realize with all this extra crap you're writing, you're speedily approaching the size of JQueryUI. JQueryUI with just it's core and tabs is only: 184.23 kb uncompressed and ~122.7 kb minified. Considering that google even hosts it for you on servers much better, faster, and numerous than yours is almost too good to be true. To not use this is, to be frank, stupid.

Comment: Because of the fact that Google hosts it, if any of your visitors have already visited a website which also uses Google's hosted version, it will simply use the copy it already downloaded. That means 0 bandwidth used, loaded from the user's computer. You can't get any better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `loadTab(2)` in the form success callback? This should be enough.

You haven't showed us your code for sending form via AJAX but I guess something similar to that should work:

```
$.post('http://example.com/ajax/form', $('form').serialize(), 
    function (data, textStatus) {
        loadTab(2);
        $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#tab2').addClass('selected');
    }
);
```

Notice that this duplicates the code for `$("#tab2").click()` function so you should consider using named function instead of anonymous in that case and reusing it in ajax callback:

```
function loadSecondTab() {
    loadTab(2);
    $('div.HOMEtabdiv ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#tab2').addClass('selected');
}

$('#tab2').click(loadSecondTab);
$.post('http://example.com/ajax/form', $('form').serialize(), loadSecondTab);
```

PS. jQuery UI is not too large. You don't have to use all it bits. You can easily just load tabs module.

Comment: He isn't capable of comprehending that, or the fact that JQueryUI has ALL OF THESE FUNCTIONS BUILT INTO IT. It's obvious he doesn't even understand the language, he's asked what is this, three questions now on the same piece of code? We're writing his site for him. Somebody jot down his address so we can send him an invoice.